# Array drop not saving

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I have an instance variable that is an array. I want to remove the last two elements and the first three elements. Then I want to remove any that are valued = nil.

The drop is not saving though:

```
@attribute_names = []

<% @attribute_names = word.attribute_names %>
  <% @attribute_names.pop(2) %>
  <% @attribute_names.drop(3) %>
<td> <%= @attribute_names %> </td>
```

The pop is working but the drop is not working in the table data. Why is that?

Comment: You shouldn't be doing the `pop` and `drop` in your view. Instead, create a second, already manipulated, variable in your controller that you access, or simply use `word.attribute_names[2..-4]`.

Comment: The method equivalent to `pop` is `shift`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The method [`pop`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-pop) removes the element from the array, and returns it.

The method [`drop`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-drop) returns *a new array* without the X first elements - the receiver stays the same!

If you want to drop the first three elements of the receiver, you can use [`slice!`](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.1/Array.html#method-i-slice-21):

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]
a.pop
# => 6
a
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a.drop(3)
# => [4, 5]
a
# => [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]
a.slice!(0, 3)
# => [1, 2, 3]
a
# => [4, 5]
```

Comment: Wondering if there is a way to get the drop() to return the same array instead of a new array?

Answer (score 1):

[Array#[range]](http://www.ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.2/Array.html#method-i-5B-5D) will do it:

```
@attribute_names = @attribute_names[2...-3]
```

Consider moving this logic into a helper method, where it can be given a name that explains why some elements are being skipped.

Comment: I will look into using a helper method. +1